# Moq to FakeItEasy migration - How to migrate Verify()?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, fakeiteasy

I'm in the process of migrating Moq tests to FakeItEasy and I have runned into a case which I don't know how to migrate.

The case is:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_EditItem()
    {
        _itemMock.Verify(
            item => item.Edit((ItemTypeId)2, (ProcessId)1, "TITLE", "TEXT", new DateTime(2012, 11, 28), (UserId)321,
                              (GroupId)321, (ItemPriorityId)1, ItemStatus.Open, (ItemTypeStatusId)3, (PlantId)0,
                              (UserId)123, 1, null, 15, "REF", It.IsAny<RegionId>(), It.IsAny<CountryId>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
    }
```

How do I migrate this call to FakeItEasy? What does it even do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moq is saying, "verify the Edit method was called with these arguments".

2 mins on the FakeItEasy docs (https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/argument-constraints/) and you should be able to say something like:

```
A.CallTo(() => item.Edit(((ItemTypeId)2, (ProcessId)1, "TITLE", "TEXT", new DateTime(2012, 11, 28), (UserId)321,
                          (GroupId)321, (ItemPriorityId)1, ItemStatus.Open, (ItemTypeStatusId)3, (PlantId)0,
                          A<UserId>.That.Matches(x=>x==(UserId)123), 1, null, 15, "REF", A<RegionId>, A<CountryId>, A<string>)).MustHaveHappened();
```

Or something similar.

```
//Moq
_mock.Verify(x=>x.method());
It.IsAny<string>()
//FIE
A.CallTo(x=>x.method()).MustHaveHappened();
A<string>.Ignored // or A<string>._
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The final solution looks like this: `A.CallTo(
                () =>
                    _itemMock.Edit((ItemTypeId) 2, (ProcessId) 1, "TITLE", "TEXT", new DateTime(2012, 11, 28),
                        (UserId) 321,
                        (GroupId) 321, (ItemPriorityId) 1, ItemStatus.Open, (ItemTypeStatusId) 3, (PlantId) 0,
                        (UserId) 123, 1, null, 15, "REF", A<RegionId>.Ignored, A<CountryId>.Ignored, A<string>.Ignored))
                .MustHaveHappened();`